# Python regex search range of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, search

I couldn't seem to find a thread on this one, but it seems like something that should be pretty simple. I'm trying to use regex to search a line in an output for a number 0-99, and do one action, but if the number is 100 then it'll do a different action. Here's what I have tried(simplified version):

```
OUTPUT = #Some command that will store the output in variable OUTPUT
OUTPUT = OUTPUT.split('\n')
for line in OUTPUT:
    if (re.search(r"Rebuild status:  percentage_complete", line)): #searches for the line, regardless of number
        if (re.search("\d[0-99]", line)): #if any number between 0 and 99 is found
            print("error")
        if (re.search("100", line)): #if number 100 is found
            print("complete")
```

I've tried this and it still picks up the 100 and prints error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This: `\d[0-99]` means a digit (`\d`), followed by a number (`0-9`) or `9`. If you are after the numeric range of `[0-99]`, you would need to use something akin to `\b\d{1,2}\b`. This will match any numeric value which is made of 1 or 2 digits.

Comment: Yes I've tried that as well but it'll still print out the error when it finds a 100

Comment: @bladexeon: The problem was that `100` was technically, a valid match for that regular expression (it would match the value of `10`). I have amended the expression to include word boundaries (the `\b`) to cope with that.

Comment: Your approach made the most sense, but I could not make the bounds work. so instead I did:
           `if re.search("\d{1,2}", line) and not re.search("100", line):`

That seemed to work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @bladexeon: If that is the case, then I recommend going for what *PM 2Ring* suggests.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify your regexes by re-ordering your number tests, and using `elif` instead of `if` on the test for 2 digit numbers.

```
for line in output:
    if re.search("Rebuild status:  percentage_complete", line): 
        if re.search("100", line):
            print "complete"
        elif re.search(r"\d{1,2}", line): 
            print "error"
```

The test for a 2 digit number is performed only if the test for "100" fails.

Using a raw string isn't strictly necessary with `r"\d{1,2}"` (in Python 2) but it's a good habit to use a raw string for any regex that contains a backslash. In Python 3, you *must* use a raw string, otherwise you get:

```
DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence '\d'
```

Note that you don't need parentheses around conditions in Python, so using them just adds unnecessary clutter.

---

As dawg mentions in the comments, the test for "100" can be tightened to `re.search(r"\b100\b", line)`, but that's not needed if we can guarantee that we're only testing integer percentages in the range 0 - 100.

Comment: Your approach made me think of another:  Match on `\d+`.  Cast the matched group to `int` and compare numerically rather than with regex.  It uses regex for what it's good at, but treats numbers as numbers rather than text.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I suppose that'd be more efficient, since it reduces the number of regex searches performed . OTOH, we could replace the search for "100" with a simple `str.find("100")`...

Comment: Note that `re.search("100", line)` will match `1000`, `-100`, `100.5` etc. Should be `re.search(r"\b100\b", line)`

Comment: @dawg: Good call, but I was being lazy, since the numbers are percentages, so those possibilities won't occur.

Answer (score 1):

0 - 99:

```
>>> s='\n'.join(["line {} text".format(i) for i in range(-2,101) ])
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?<!\-)\b(\d\d|\d)\b', s)
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99']
```

The regex `'(?<!\-)\b(\d\d|\d)\b'` matches 2 digits 0-99 and does not match negative numbers such as `-9`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qS3jD5/1)

100 is easy: `'(?<!\-)\b100\b'`

If you do not want to match floats: `\b(?<![-.])(\d\d|\d)(?!\.)\b`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qS3jD5/2)

Comment: Is there anything similarly simple to match digits 0-199?